# Django: Accessing list attributes in template

Tags: python, html, mysql, django

I have a SQL query in a Django view and store the results in a variable. As far I know the result should be stored as a list.

```
def assignments(request):

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT o.article_id, o.amount, m.id, o.create_date, m.status FROM orders o, producers p, machines ma, matches m WHERE ma.producer_id=1 AND m.machine_id = ma.id AND m.order_id = o.id")
    articles = cursor.fetchall()

    context = {"article_list": articles}

    return render(request, 'assignments.html', context)
```

Then I want to transfer that data row by row in a table in my template.

```
{% block body %}
<div class="container">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>...</thead>
            <tbody>
              {% for articles in article_list %}
                <tr>
                  <td>{{ articles.article_id }}</td>
                  <td>{{ articles.amount }}</td>
                  <td>{{ articles.id}}</td>
                  <td>{{ articles.create_date }}</td>
                  <td>{{ articles.status }}</td>
                </tr>
              {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Unfortunately the table is empty and is not showing any results.
The query itself should be fine. I tested the query in my database workbench and it is showing the correct results.

How can I access the data stored in variable `articles` from my template?

PS: I'm far from being a programmer. So I don't really know any programming concepts/language.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Comment: I would suggest that you don't use raw sql for this query. This can easily be done with ORM

Comment: Are you sure that your article_list is not empty

Comment: @ArpitSolanki: Yes, if I just add {{ article_list }} in the template it prints the following result: "((6093, 1, 30.0, 1, datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 29, 10, 54, 45), datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 29, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 31, 0, 0), 1),)".

Comment: I also tried to do this with ORM, but I failed to express the join statements. But thanks for that hint. I will try to use ORM again.

Answer (score 1):

You have a list of lists. Each element in `articles_list` is just a list of values from the database; it does not have any knowledge of attributes like "id" or "amount".

As Arpit says in the comments, you should be using Django models for this rather than raw SQL.

Comment: Thanks four your answer. That makes sense. However, is there still a way to access the single elements in article_list? I also would love using Django models, but I'm really struggling to join the tables with ORM.